# KeyListener on panel in java Swing. Wrong output

Tags: java, swing

I want to move the white box up and down using 'w''s''a''d' keys. This is my code :

```
static int matrix[][] = { { 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1 }, { 1, 0, 0, 0,0,0 }, { 1, 3, 1, 1,0,0 }, {1,0,1,0,0,0}, {1,0,1,2,2,1}, {1,1,1,1,1,1}  };
JPanel easyPanel(){

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 6, 0, 0));


    int rowNumber = 0; 
    int colNumber = 0; 


    for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
        if(colNumber == 6){
            colNumber = 0;
            rowNumber++; 
        }
        JLabel l = new JLabel();


        if(matrix[rowNumber][colNumber] == 0){
                l.setBackground(Color.pink);
            }
        else if(matrix[rowNumber][colNumber]==2){
            l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("cross.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));


        }

else if(matrix[rowNumber][colNumber]==3){
                l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("icon.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
                int row = rowNumber;
                int col = colNumber;
                addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                    //move();
                }
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                    //move();.
                }
                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
                    panel.setVisible(false);
                    matrix[row][col] = 0;
                    move(ke,row,col);
                }
            });
            }




   private void move(KeyEvent ke,int row,int col){
        if(ke.getKeyChar() == 'w'){
            System.out.println("Pressed up");
            matrix[row-1][col] = 3;
            JPanel newGame = easyPanel(); 
            newGame.setVisible(true);
            add(newGame); 

        }
        else if(ke.getKeyChar() =='s'){
            System.out.println("Pressed down");
            matrix[row+1][col] = 3;
            JPanel newGame = easyPanel(); 
            newGame.setVisible(true);
            add(newGame);
        }
        else if(ke.getKeyChar() == 'a'){
            System.out.println("Pressed left");
            matrix[row][col-1] = 3;
            JPanel newGame = easyPanel(); 
            newGame.setVisible(true);
            add(newGame);
        }
        else if(ke.getKeyChar() == 'd'){
            System.out.println("Pressed right");
            matrix[row][col+1] = 3;
            JPanel newGame = easyPanel(); 
            newGame.setVisible(true);
            add(newGame);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
```

But i am getting output something like this : 
Default :
[image]

First Move 'w' - correct:
[image]

Next move 'd' - insted of moving a block, it moves makes two blocks white:
[image]

Where am I going wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First, I'd rely in the `KeyEvent.VK_` constants over the character codes, but that's me. I'd also consider using the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener` as it will solve the focus related issues

Comment: @MadProgrammer okay i will give all that a look. Any suggestions on how i can fix this program?

Comment: Instead of recreating the panel each time, consider having a mechanism which can update the labels instead, based on the changes to the model (so you're not having to update the entire state of the UI, only what changes)

Comment: *"Any suggestions on how i can fix this program?"* - You only ever change the state of the matrix to `3`, you never change the previous position to been `0` (I think that's what you want) - so when you update the UI, it's painting white cells everywhere the player has been

Comment: Also, you seem to be adding multiple `KeyListener` for all the `3` positions which may cause multiple key events to be triggered

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am making the previous position to be 0. Check the line before i am calling the move() method in keylistener.

Comment: Yep, picked that up, shame you're registering a new `KeyListener` every time `easyPanel` is called ;)

Comment: And just for the record: next, please properly format / indent all of your source code. Never allow your code to look messy; not here; not at home in your IDE.

Answer (score 2):

So based on this...

```
} else if (matrix[rowNumber][colNumber] == 3) {
    l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("icon.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
    int row = rowNumber;
    int col = colNumber;
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
            //move();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            //move();.
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
            panel.setVisible(false);
            matrix[row][col] = 0;
            move(ke, row, col);
        }
    });
}
```

Each time `easyPanel` is called and it finds a `3` in the matrix, it adds a new `KeyListener`, assuming you're updating the matrix correctly, this means that the first time it's called, you register one `KeyListener`, then the next time you call `easyPanel`, you add another and so and so forth.

The `KeyListener` should be registered separately and done so only once.  In fact, I'd highly recommend using the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`, as it will solve the focus related issues

I'd also consider a different update model.  Instead of re-creating the UI each time, simply have another matrix of `JLabel`s, which is first created based on the `matrix` values.

You can then update the `matrix`

```
matrix[row][col] = 0;
```

Then update the label

```
updateUI(row, col);
```

which could do something like...

```
switch (matrix[row][col]) {
    case 0: labels[row][col].setIcon(null);
            break;  
    case 2: labels[row][col].setIcon(crossIcon);  
            break;  
    case 3: labels[row][col].setIcon(playerIcon);  
            break;  
}
repaint();
```

This will reduce the amount of overhead and reduce the risk of flickering.

You should also pre-cache and re-use your icons